# SQL Server : get permissions of user containing column level permissions

Tags: sql-server, user-permissions

I found following very helpful SQL Server code that gets all permissions of a user (here testuser) in a SQL Server database:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'DOMAIN\testuser'; 

-- Server rights
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER');

-- Database rights
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'DATABASE');

-- Specific per object rights
SELECT 
    T.TABLE_TYPE AS OBJECT_TYPE, T.TABLE_SCHEMA AS [SCHEMA_NAME], 
    T.TABLE_NAME AS [OBJECT_NAME], P.PERMISSION_NAME 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
CROSS APPLY 
    fn_my_permissions(T.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T.TABLE_NAME, 'OBJECT') P
WHERE 
    P.subentity_name = ''

UNION

SELECT 
    R.ROUTINE_TYPE AS OBJECT_TYPE, R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA AS [SCHEMA_NAME], 
    R.ROUTINE_NAME AS [OBJECT_NAME], P.PERMISSION_NAME
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES R
CROSS APPLY 
    fn_my_permissions(R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA + '.' + R.ROUTINE_NAME, 'OBJECT') P
ORDER BY 
    OBJECT_TYPE, [SCHEMA_NAME], [OBJECT_NAME], P.PERMISSION_NAME

REVERT;
GO
```

But I also need the column-level permissions which are not shown by this code.

Can anyone please extend the code, so it also returns the column-level permissions?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subentity_name column from [fn_my_permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097(v=sql.120).aspx) should give you what you want.

```
-- Specific per object rigths
SELECT T.TABLE_TYPE AS OBJECT_TYPE, T.TABLE_SCHEMA AS [SCHEMA_NAME], T.TABLE_NAME AS [OBJECT_NAME], NULLIF(P.subentity_name, '') as COLUMN_NAME, P.PERMISSION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
CROSS APPLY fn_my_permissions(T.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T.TABLE_NAME, 'OBJECT') P
UNION
SELECT R.ROUTINE_TYPE AS OBJECT_TYPE, R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA AS [SCHEMA_NAME], R.ROUTINE_NAME AS [OBJECT_NAME], NULLIF(P.subentity_name, '') as COLUMN_NAME, P.PERMISSION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES R
CROSS APPLY fn_my_permissions(R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA + '.' + R.ROUTINE_NAME, 'OBJECT') P
ORDER BY OBJECT_TYPE, [SCHEMA_NAME], [OBJECT_NAME], COLUMN_NAME, P.PERMISSION_NAME
```

Comment: thx, I tried this and it shows a the additional column "COLUMN_NAME" but it is always NULL. The Table with the Colum-level permissions does not even occure in the results.

Comment: Ooops - shouldn't have left `WHERE P.subentity_name = ''` in. You will now see the column names.

Comment: One little last improofment: put COLUMN_NAME into the ORDER BY line: ORDER BY OBJECT_TYPE, [SCHEMA_NAME], [OBJECT_NAME], [COLUMN_NAME], P.PERMISSION_NAME